# How to make the recursive menu in meteor

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, recursion

1) I wanted to make a recursive menu and stops when the submenu is starting to repeat from the previous menu. 
This is my database:-

```
   "categories": [
           {
               "id": "root1",
               "status": true,
               "name": "/",
               "slug": "_root",
               "childs": [
                   "A1",
                   "A2",
                   "A3"
               ]
           },
           {
              "name": [
                  {
                      "la": "en",
                      "text": "Brands"
                  }
              ],
              "slug": "brands",
              "status": true,
              "id": "A1",
              "childs": [
                  "B1"
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": [
                  {
                      "la": "en",
                      "text": "Chair"
                  }
              ],
              "slug": "chair",
              "status": true,
              "id": "B1",
              "childs": ["C1",
                        "C2"
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": [
                  {
                      "la": "en",
                      "text": "Wooden chair"
                  }
              ],
              "slug": "wooden-chair",
              "status": true,
              "id": "C1",
              "childs": ["B1"]
          }
        ]
```

navigation.html

```
<template name="navigation">
{{#if root}}
                    {{#each root}}
                        {{#if this.status}}
                            {{> navigation_categories item=this}}
                        {{/if}}
                    {{/each}}
                {{else}}
                    <li class=""><a href="">{{__ this.name}}</a></li>
                {{/if}}
</template>
```

navigation.js

```
Template.navigation.helpers({
    root(){
        var tpl = Template.instance(),
    company = Company.findOne({"_id":tpl.companyID});
        if (company){
            let categories = company.showcase.categories,
                root =  _.findWhere(categories, {'slug' : '_root' });
            return _.map(root.childs, (id) => {
                let category = _.findWhere(categories, { 'id' : id });
                category.tree = _.compact(_.flatten(_.union(category.tree, '_root')));
                return category;
            })
        }
    }
});
```

navigation_categories.html

```
<template name="navigation_categories">
    {{#if children}}
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{pathFor 'company.showcase.category.index' id=item.id}}">P{{__ item.name}}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                {{#each children}}
                    {{#if this.status}}
                        {{>navigation_categories item=this}}
                    {{/if}}
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{else}}
            <a href="{{pathFor 'company.showcase.category.index' id=item.id}}">T{{__ item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

navigation_categories.js

```
Template.navigation_categories.helpers({
  children(){
    var tpl = Template.instance(),
    company = Company.findOne({"_id":tpl.companyID});
    var categories=company.showcase.categories;
    var item = this.item;
    var tree = item.tree;
    if(!_.contains(tree, item.slug)&& item.childs.length > 0){
      return _.map(item.childs, (childID) => {
        var category = _.findWhere(categories, { id : childID });
        category.tree = _.compact(_.flatten(_.union(tree, category.slug)));
          return category;
      })
    }else {
      return null;
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is the recursive stops at id:B1 and does not continue to the children. How to solve this?

Comment: Well, you are not giving much to go on by way of explanation, and debugging other peoples code visually is really not easy, but if I had to take a stab in the dark I'd say it was your `children()` helper, which appears to send back a list of "category" objects that do not have a `status` or a `children`, both of which are things your template are looking for in the `{{#if}}`s.  I'd suggest putting some `console.log()` statements all over, see whats being returned, and make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, what i really want is the menu should have 3 levels accordingly like ID: A1, B1,C1 then just stop the recursion here. because the C1 has the child id of A1, and that would cause infinite loops. Therefore this line => var tree=item.this; I want this to hold the A1,B1 and C1. but when i console.log(tree); it will only appear id of A1 and B1 only. I define the item.slug and length of the childs, if the tree already has the same slug it will return null. if the tree did not have the same slug it will continue the recursion.. help me please..

Comment: So, again, it looks like your return type you are returning from your helper function differs from what your template is testing on.  I suggest you print out the returned values from the `.map()` you are performing, as it appears you are missing some key fields.

Comment: A better way to model a tree is usually to just have each child refer to its parent (one to zero or one) instead of each parent referring to its children (1 to zero or N). This avoids children having multiple parents for example and you can always start with the node that has no parent.